# How can I count the number of NAs per group?

Tags: r, count, aggregate, na

Could someone please explain why I get different answers using the aggregate function to count missing values by group?  Also, is there a better way to count missing values by group using a native R function?

```
DF <- data.frame(YEAR=c(2000,2000,2000,2001,2001,2001,2001,2002,2002,2002), X=c(1,NA,3,NA,NA,NA,7,8,9,10))
DF

aggregate(X ~ YEAR, data=DF, function(x) { sum(is.na(x)) })
with(DF, aggregate(X, list(YEAR), function(x) { sum(is.na(x)) }))

aggregate(X ~ YEAR, data=DF, function(x) { sum(! is.na(x)) })
with(DF, aggregate(X, list(YEAR), function(x) { sum(! is.na(x)) }))
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The help page at `?aggregate` points out that the formula method has an argument `na.action` which is set by default to `na.omit`.

> `na.action`: *a function which indicates what should happen when the data contain `NA` values. The default is to ignore missing values in the given variables.*

Change that argument to `NULL` or `na.pass` instead to get the results you are probably expecting:

```
# aggregate(X ~ YEAR, data=DF, function(x) {sum(is.na(x))}, na.action = na.pass)
aggregate(X ~ YEAR, data=DF, function(x) {sum(is.na(x))}, na.action = NULL)
#   YEAR X
# 1 2000 1
# 2 2001 3
# 3 2002 0
```

Answer (score 4):

An option using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>% 
    group_by(YEAR) %>% 
    summarise(sum_na = sum(is.na(x)))
```

Or if you want to use `across` to dynamically select columns:

```
DF %>% 
    group_by(YEAR) %>% 
    summarise(across(X,  ~sum(is.na(.))))
```

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
   YEAR sum_na
  <dbl>  <int>
1  2000      1
2  2001      3
3  2002      0
```

Answer (score -3):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

#say you want to get missing values from group 1
dataframe %>% filter(group = 1 & is.na(another_column))

#missing values from group 2
dataframe %>% filter(group = 2 & is.na(another_column))
```

Comment: This doesn't answer how to count NA's during an aggregate or group by